# Understanding google's HTML

Tags: python, html

first time poster here.

I am just getting into python and coding in general and I am looking into the requests and BeutifulSoup libraries. I am trying to grab image url’s from google images. When inspecting the site in chrome i can find the “div” and the correct img src url. But when I open the HTML that “requests” gives me I can find the same “div” but the img src url is something completely different and only leads to a black page if used.

[Img of the HTML requests get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3YP3.png)

[Img of the HTML found in chrome's inspect tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfQR0.png)

**What I wonder, and want to understand is:**

1. why are these HTML's different
2. How do I get the img src that is found with the inspect tool with requests?

Hope the question makes sense and thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, your code retrieves a single HTML page, and lets you access it, as it was retrieved. The browser, on the other hand, retrieves that HTML, but then lets the scripts embedded in (or linked from) it run, and these scripts often make significant modifications to the HTML (also known as DOM - Document Object Model). The browser's inspector inspects the fully modified DOM.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe differences between the  the response HTML and the code in chrome inspector stems for updates to the page when JS changes it . for example when you use innerHTML() to edit div element  so the code you add will add to DOM stack   so as the code in the inspector but it would have no influence on the response.
2. You may search the `http://` in the begging and the `.png` or `.jpg` or any other image format in the end.

Comment: What I want my program to do is to be able to get the first image on google images for any given search word given by the user. So i need to be able to scrape the requests HTML for the first search results image url, but the HTML i get does not provide that, is there another way i should tackle this?

Comment: I dont know a solution for presenting the html code dynamically as the inspector but you may looks for the srcs buy finding the first http;/ (it may not be the first but i believe that before the first image there is constant number of urls before the first image url)

Comment: @Mogas up last massage

Comment: The url for the images does not seem to be in the http format but the links ar rather (as shown in the second image) some other format, as they start with: "data:image....."

Comment: @Mogas isn't even batter?